# Node referencing: How do you display (with VIEWS) a node(edition) with all its references (articles)?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

Ingredients:

- Drupal7 + References + Views module installed 2 content types:
  magazine issue + magazine articles (for each issue)
- Article c-type    has a reference field: issue_no which displays the
  issue it belongs
- I made a Views to display me a plain list of    issues only.

Requirements

**1. When I click on the issue in the issue list I want to see all its references nodes(=articles) attached**

**2. I need to highlight the latest issue in the list by creating a separate page VIEW on the frontpage that contains articles of the latest view.**

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I have done something similar for a project. In **article view page** go to advanced-> add a contextual filter of issue no. In  **magazine issue view page** in fields-> add -> add a custom text field -> rewrite results -> select Output this field as a link to link it to your **article view page** with argument as **issue no**.

For example if your article list view page is `article_list`, you can add a rewrite result in custom text as `article_list/[field_issue_no]`; where `[field_issue_no]` is your issue no field.